# Unable to find a package for groovy, like cereal_port package in fuerte?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

the cereal_port package in fuerte provides easy programming for USB port communication but i am unable to found such a package for groovy. 
rosserial package in groovy is very much typed for communication with AVR or with a microcontroller running rosserial_client.
the problem is that I have a robot base having PIC microcontroller with FTDI device. means the base is having a microcontroller based circuit for motor control. the microcontroller can actually handle RS-232 and the FTDI device converts RS-232 data in to packets of USB to support the communication. I just need to send specific data to USB port. 
I am unable to write a rosnode to send data on USB0 port?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/67606/unable-to-find-a-package-for-groovy,-like-cereal_port-package-in-fuerte?/) by [lifelonglearner](https://answers.ros.org/users/5249/lifelonglearner/) on ROS Answers with karma: 205 on 2013-07-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[cereal_port](http://ros.org/wiki/cereal_port) is part of the [serial_communication](http://ros.org/wiki/serial_communication) stack.

From the documentation, it looks like the serial_communication stack is no longer maintained, and is not available in Groovy. You may be able to build it from source, or contact the maintainers to get it released into Groovy.

As an alternative, the [serial](http://williamjwoodall.com/serial/) library is available in Groovy and should do what you need.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2013-07-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lifelonglearner](https://answers.ros.org/users/5249/lifelonglearner/) on 2013-07-18**:
Following is the problem I am facing while. CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:5 (find_package):
Could not find module Findcatkin.cmake or a configuration file for package
catkin.

Adjust CMAKE_MODULE_PATH to find Findcatkin.cmake or set catkin_DIR to the
directory containing a CMake configuratio

**Comment by [lifelonglearner](https://answers.ros.org/users/5249/lifelonglearner/) on 2013-07-18**:
file for catkin.  The file will have one of the following names:
catkinConfig.cmake
catkin-config.cmake
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:9 (catkin_package):
Unknown CMake command "catkin_package".
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
make: *** [serial] Error 1

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2013-07-18**:
If you're having trouble with the serial library, please ask a new question. You should be able to install it with 'sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-serial' instead of building it from source.

**Comment by [lifelonglearner](https://answers.ros.org/users/5249/lifelonglearner/) on 2013-07-18**:
Thank you. I tried 'sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-serial'  there was a little problem but 'sudo apt-get updates' resolved the problem and finally I got to install serial.
I wish I will be able to program to send data on USB0 using serial. Thanks a lot.

**Comment by [lifelonglearner](https://answers.ros.org/users/5249/lifelonglearner/) on 2013-07-22**:
I got to install the Serial and trying to write program I am having problem to resolve the #include <unix.h>. Compiler ('eclipse' made it compatible to rosworkspace) showing problem to resolve it. What I understand is that unix.h directory is not available. Please tell how to resolve this problem.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2013-07-23**:
If you're having trouble with the serial library, please ask a new question.